# Javascript time counter for calling ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a number of different form elements. When any of the form elements have their value changed, I need to make an ajax call 500ms after the change.

However, should another form element have its value changed then I would like to reset the timer to 500ms, thus avoiding multiple Ajax requests for a series of changes that happen within 500ms of each other.

Is there a JavaScript or jQuery solution to this requirement?

Comment: please first try urself, if you already tried the show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that demonstrates the principles you're looking for:

```
// Keeps track of the timer id in a scope that is outside of the event function
// The variable will remain in memory and available to the next event call
var myTimer;

// Detect changes on keyup.
$('.textbox').on('keyup', function () {
    console.log('keyup');
    setMyTimer(500);
});
// Detect on change.
$('select').on('change', function () {
    console.log('change');
    setMyTimer(1000);
});

function setMyTimer(timerDelay) {
    // if myTimer has a value, then we should clear the timer. This stops us
    // from queuing multiple timers
    if (myTimer) {
        console.log('clear tiemout');
        clearTimeout(myTimer);
    }

    // Set the timer. It will be cleared if there is another handled 'keyup' 
    // event sooner than the timerDelay parameter
    myTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Ajax stuff');
        // ajax stuff
    }, timerDelay);
};
```

Remove the `console.log` code before using in production.

See this working demonstration:

**http://jsfiddle.net/cC6Dq/5/**

Comment: I changed the answer to show the suitability of using this code for multiple event types on different elements.